# Invoking QGIS style dialog from Python standalone script

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I can load a layer, open a canvas, and draw the layer in the canvas using the Qgis python API.

Can I bring up the properties dialog, or even just the "Style" tab of the properties dialog, from such a standalone application? I have a bad feeling I can't because all the code is in the main Qgis Application rather than present in qgis.core and qgis.gui, and doesn't have a python interface.

Unless I've missed something, the solution might be to rebuild the dialog and its behaviour in Python, re-using the relevant .ui file?

Comment: Do you need style or labels also? Style is all in `gui` but labels are not yet.

Comment: Style would be good for a start! I should probably add I'm using 2.14 Essen at the moment.

Comment: You can take a look at http://webgeodatavore.github.io/pyqgis-samples/ (disclaimer: I'm the author or this content) to find out most Python QGIS gui API components visually with sample code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following dialog if you need only style:

`QgsRendererV2PropertiesDialog`

Usage:

```
dlg = QgsRendererV2PropertiesDialog(layer, QgsStyleV2.defaultStyle(), embedded=False)
dlg.setMapCanvas(canvas)
dlg.exec_()
```

Comment: Yes! Needs a `canvas.refresh()` to reflect changes unless I can add an "apply" button with my Qt skillz...